# WEBStorm / PHPStorm- middle click moves cursor

Tags: mouseevent, mouse, phpstorm, webstorm

I've just installed PHPStorm (and WEBStorm - I do frontend, but also work on dev projects and need phpstorm to correctly highlight the sintax of php files).
I have to say, they're both great products... except for one very annoying behavior. When you middle-click somewhere in the document, it moves the cursor to that position. If I needed the cursor to be moved there, I would have simply left-clicked. Whenever I middle-click, it's because I'm coming from another monitor/app and I quickly want to switch focus to phpstorm (and not having to Alt+Tab 100 times), NOT move the cursor from where it was (because I want to continue typing from where I left it). This is very annoying and I've searched through settings in the "Keymap" section bindings for "cursor" or "caret", couldn't find anything relevant.

Where can you disable middle-click from moving the cursor inside the document or doing anything else? So when you middle click anywhere on the phpstorm window the only thing that happens is, naturally, getting focus on the app, to be able to continue typing exactly from where you left the cursor when you've initially left the app before switching to another app?

Comment: AFAIK, it's "Go to declaration" shortcut. Also, PhpStorm have all functionality of WebStorm and even more (PHP, DB).

Comment: (1). I've already tried to delete the mouse binding from "Go to declaration", only left Ctrl+Click. But middle click still moves the caret. It just doesn't seek to "Go to declaration"


(2). I am using WebStorm8, which is much better for frontend work. PhpStorm doesn't have "multiple carets" for example, which is indispensable while building html. So, if I'm only doing html/css/js on a project, I work in webstorm. If there is any php envolved, phpstorm clearly.

Comment: PhpStorm EAP has multiple caret option: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program .

Comment: What's your keymap scheme in File | Settings | IDE settings  | Keymap (Preferences | Keymap for Mac OS).

Comment: @Kootli I don't know what do you mean by "what's your keymap scheme?". I thought you wanted me to export it or something alike, but there is no "export" option.

Comment: what's the name of the scheme?

Comment: I agree with you @MrCroft this is very annoying. I don't like this caret moving behavior in any application actually.